# Is there a way to stop beeline from generating CR character?

Tags: hive, redhat, hiveql, beeline, bigdata

When I redirect the output of beeline to a file, I can see that the file generated has ^M (CR, carriage return, 0x0D hex) character inside which is placed at around column 144, presumably as a way to wrap around text output.

Is there a way to turn this off in beeline? Or maybe inform beeline of a different column width.

I have: `Beeline version 1.2.1000.2.5.0.0-1245 by Apache Hive`

Comment: This is a bad practice. Use `INSERT OVERWRITE [LOCAL] DIRECTORY` instead. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries

Comment: I am not performing a write to hive. I am just running a SELECT statement. The beeline output from the SELECT has embedded CR.

Comment: `INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY` is used to dump query results to the local file system

Comment: Does that output to HDFS?

Comment: Depends on the optional keyword `LOCAL`

Comment: When I use LOCAL, I find no file is created even though beeline/hive reports that something is created. Without LOCAL, a directory with a binary file in HDFS is created, which I do not know how to parse

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> set hive.exec.compress.output=false;
>
> INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'hdfs_dir' 'query_here';

When you are using **LOCAL** you need to make sure that you are running the script / query on the node(machine) where Hiveserver2 is running. In case you run from another machine it will not fail, but still creates a file in the node where HS2 is running.